Using pyplot for a remote server in VS
Currently trying to get started with VS Code for my research group. I connected to a remote host via SSH and I'm trying to get Python up and running. I'm particularly interested in importing pyplot. I use anaconda as the interpreter for my local machine and it works fine, but the remote host doesn't have this option and I don't have permission to alter anything on it. Attached is the Python terminal after running the code to import the modules.
To be quite frank, I'm at a loss for what to try as far as a fix goes. Coding and computer programming have never been strong areas for me, so I would immensely appreciate any help!

To import pyplot on a remote server where you can’t install Anaconda, you can try using a virtual environment with the required packages installed. Here’s what you can do:

Create a virtual environment on the remote server (if you have permission to do so):
python -m venv myenv

Activate the virtual environment:
source myenv/bin/activate

Install matplotlib (which includes pyplot) in the virtual environment:
pip install matplotlib


After these steps, try running your Python code again. It should be able to import pyplot from matplotlib.
If you don’t have permission to create a virtual environment, you might need to ask the system administrator to install matplotlib for you or provide an alternative solution.

Hey there, thanks a ton for your help. I gave it a shot but I think my access is insufficient. I was able to find  workaround by using a matplotlib command. (matplotlib.use('Agg')).
